# How can I detect is the Bluetooth of the user's iPhone Off or On?

Tags: swift, bluetooth

I am trying to detect is the Bluetooth of the user's iPhone On or Off. If it is Off I want to send a notification to the user to turn it On.
So far I have done this:

```
import CoreBluetooth

  class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate,CBManager {   

 var myBTManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

  }

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    print(#function)
    if peripheral.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
        print("Broadcasting...")

    //    myBTManager!.startAdvertising(_broadcastBeaconDict)
    } else if peripheral.state == CBManagerState.poweredOff {
        print("Stopped")
        myBTManager!.stopAdvertising()
    } else if peripheral.state == CBManagerState.unsupported {
        print("Unsupported")
    } else if peripheral.state == CBManagerState.unauthorized {
        print("This option is not allowed by your application")
    }
}
```

But as You can see from the picture, something is wrong.[image]

Would you please help me how to fix this issue, I am new to swift and CoreBluetooth technology. I am also using Reachability for detecting the Wi-Fi connection, so if it also works for Bluetooth, I would prefer to use Reachability then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should be implementing the protocol `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`, so replace `CBManager` in your `class` definition line with `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`.
2. In Swift 3, the signature of `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` is now:

   ```
   func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
   ```
3. You can't initialize the `CBPeripheralManager` at class creation time since `self` is only available after the class has been initialized.  Instead, make your property:

   ```
   var myBTManager: CBPeripheralManager?
   ```

   and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       ...       
       myBTManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CBCentralMangerDelegate` method:

```
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
            if central.state == .poweredOn {
                //Bluetooth is on
           } else if central.state == .poweredOff {
                //Bluetooth is off
           }
    }
```